# ILB App Service Environment Outbound Traffic

Tags: azure, routes, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way that we can route outbound traffic going out from an ILB ASE to an static internal IP?

I understand that App Service Plans get assigned an IP dynamically from the subnet the ASE belongs to, but we have a need to make sure traffic comes to our on-premise data center from a static IP.

Comment: you can use forced tunneling to route your outbound traffic to NVA or express route.

Comment: removed thanks as that is not really needed, added extra tag

Comment: If you use an ILB ASE, the outbound IP address will not change so long as your ASE stays up and running. So what do you want in this case?

Comment: App Service Plans gets a dynamic IP (that belongs to the ASE subnet). I need to host an application (and have the ability to scale up and down) and know about the IP the Web App is using so I can do some NAT translations on the on premises network.

Answer (score 1):

As for as I know, apps running in an App Service environment get **static**, **dedicated IP addresses** both for inbound and outbound connections. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-addresses). As you said, we can't beforehand which IP address will be assigned app instance to make the outbound connection if there are scaled-out instances. Even now I could not find any official doc to define this. It's welcome to give feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/16790656-add-static-ip-address-for-outbound-traffic-without).

Besides, if you want to route your ASE outbound traffic somewhere instead of directly routing to the internet, you can configure your App Service Environment with forced tunneling from this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/forced-tunnel-support).